# python/sql using a binary string of 48 digits to represent half hour intervals in a day

Tags: python, sql

So, I am working on a small project and I am stumped. I am using an existing sql database to lookup values. The table that has me stumped is a table that is used to setup different time periods on a per day basis, which uses binary as logic, 48 digits to represent half hour periods.

SQL Table has columns Day1(Sun) - Day7(Sat) each with 48 digit "binary" strings

For example Day 1 = Sunday, which has a 48 digit string "111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000" which would represent that this particular day has from 00:00 to 11:59(1) would be valid and from 12:00 to 23:59 would be invalid(0).

What I would like to do, is check if an event is valid based on the event time compared to this table. So if an event happened Sunday at 11:00 it would check the table on day 1(Sunday) and find that the the digit representing that time is 1 then we are valid. Or if another event occurred at 1:15 it would be invalid as that would be a zero. I can't wrap my brain around how to translate this binary logic to something usable in python, I am thinking a translation table of some sort but still new to python so not sure if there is an existing library I can use or some simple way of doing this that I can't see. Hoping to get pointed in the right direction. Basically how to interpet to python that the left most digit represents 00:00 to 00:29 and so on.

Comment: You could `split()` the character string into a list representing each half-hour segment, then when you need to do a check, figure out which segment the event occurs in using some datetime wrangling, then check the digit at that index in the check list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that indicates how to calculate the mapping.

- Convert 12-hour times to 24-hour.
- Calculate which 30-minute period the given time is 'in'.
- Use that number to select the appropriate character from the string.

-

```
from math import floor

validity = "111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000"

hours = 1
minutes = 15
am_or_pm = 'PM'

if am_or_pm == 'PM':
    hours += 12
total_minutes = 60*hours+minutes
print ('total_minutes', total_minutes)
period = total_minutes // 30
print ('period', period)
print ('validity', validity[period])
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! That seems like the easiest method!

Comment: Welcome! -------